# JQuery for each anchor href replace thumbnail img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Dont laugh, this is my weak attempt at trying to get each anchor links href and replacing the image source for .product-thumbnail img

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //var findImage = $('dd.variation-File ul li a').attr('href');

    //get the anchor link to image
    x=$('dd.variation-File ul li a').toArray();

    //replace default thumbnail with anchor link from x
    y=$('td.product-thumbnail img').toArray();

    y.each().attr['src'].replace(this, x);
});
</script>
```

On our cart page there is a table that displays cart info.  There are multiple image (previews) and **if an image was uploaded** then there is a `dd.variation-File ul li` with an anchor, I simply am trying to write a script that if `dd.variation-File ul li a` exists, replace the img src for `.product-thumbnail img` with the href found in `dd.variation-file ul li a`

Thanks for helping out a noob :)

Comment: Could you post the HTML?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ckjFmPiN

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
y.each(function(){
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(this, x));
});
```

But I don't know what it will do, since `replace` accepts a string instead of an array.

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure .replace would even be the right way to go -- Here is what I get in the console when trying your suggestion: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'y.each(function(){
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace(this, x));
})')